# Lua-Logging data from Device to a file-Excel- Lua scripts

Tags: lua

I have the following Lua script that collects temperature values from a device and I would like to log the output data below to an excel spreadsheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
if globalsFile == nil then
dofile("globals.lua")
end

if utilFile == nil then
dofile("util.lua")
end

heaterDuration = 0
heaterInterval = 2
heaterTimeout = 20
index = 1

heater.ON()
print("The heaters have been turned on")
print("Temperatures will be updated below every " .. heaterInterval .. " seconds")
print("Item,Time Point,Top,Bottom,Ambient")

tempIncrease = 'n'
while (heaterDuration < heaterTimeout) do
topTemp = heater.top()
bottomTemp = heater.bottom()
ambientTemp = temperature.ambient()
print(index .. "," .. heaterDuration .. "," .. topTemp .. "," .. bottomTemp .. "," .. ambientTemp)
heaterDuration = heaterDuration + heaterInterval
os.sleep(heaterInterval * 1000)
end

Output

Item,Time Point,Top,Bottom,Ambient
1,0,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.257425308228
1,2,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,4,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,6,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,8,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,10,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,12,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,14,37.022724151611,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,16,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784
1,18,37.022136688232,37.202819824219,28.282178878784```
````

Comment: What am I missing? That looks like CSV (comma separated values), which is a format the Excel is happy to read without further changes. Just write that to a `*.csv` file and open it with Excel or most (or all) other spreadsheet software.

Comment: What is the function to write to *.csv? I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: CSV is just plain text. Just print out a value, the comma character (literally ","), a value, the comma character, etc, until the end of a line. Then print a new line character. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `while` loop with something like this, depending on the environment that your Lua runs in, you should be creating a CSV file, which is a readable plain text file with literally just values (or strings, but then it can get more complicated) values separated by commas, or tabs, but let's stick to commas here.

The biggest differences are the creation of the `mycsv` file object, switchin the `print` to `mycsv:write()` (while making sure there is a newline), and then closing (and maybe flushing unwritten data) the file object at the end.

```lua
mycsv = io.open("mydata.csv", "w")
mycsv:write("Item,Time Point,Top,Bottom,Ambient\n")
while (heaterDuration < heaterTimeout) do
    topTemp = heater.top()
    bottomTemp = heater.bottom()
    ambientTemp = temperature.ambient()
    mycsv:write(index .. "," .. heaterDuration .. "," .. topTemp .. "," ..
                bottomTemp .. "," .. ambientTemp .. "\n")
    heaterDuration = heaterDuration + heaterInterval
    os.sleep(heaterInterval * 1000)
end
mycsv:close()
```

See also: https://luabyexample.org/docs/files/

Comment: Thank you very much Erwin! You are the "Man"  and last question any ideas on the columns header:  "Item, Time Point, Top, Bottom, Ambient" I have tried it, but got a few errors.

Comment: Just move that `print()` statement after the `io.open()` (and make it a `write()` call), so that it's included in the file that you write, and make sure you have a `\n` at the end like with the lines of data, and it should work just fine.

Comment: mycsv = io.open("mydata.csv", "w")
mycsv:write(print("Item","TimePoint","top","Bottom","Ambient", "\n")) - would that work?

Comment: `mycsv:write("Item,Time Point,Top,Bottom,Ambient\n")`